# use install4j show ClassNotFoundException error

Tags: install4j

i use install4j create a install Application,i install the Application in my computer,
but when i open the Application ,it show error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BOOT-INF.classes.com.lwpoct.lwproject.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:80)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
```

how can i solve it,thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main class of your launcher has to be configured as `com.lwpoct.lwproject.Application` and not as `BOOT-INF.classes.com.lwpoct.lwproject.Application`.